# Syslog with JSON Data Parsing using PyParsing

Tags: python, json, syslog, pyparsing

I want to make a Syslog parser for me to transform my Syslog, which has JSON information in a key=value format and the output file to be a .txt for me to import into FortiSIEM, which is really picky with the compatible syslogs, and I can't get to working parsing the "Original" syslog, thus this idea for me to simplify the log before it reaches the SIEM.

I have made some testing with PyParsing but I really don't know how to use it, My output file is being created but it's coming out blank

I think I can't share the syslog, so here a very rough example on how the syslog looks like:

<140>1 2022-05-02T08:31:22.478Z **platform** dataexport - **syslog_variation** - {"key"=value, info:{"key"=value, "key"=value, "key"=value}, info2:{"key"=value, "key"=value},"key"=value}

The script that I have come up with:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Suppress, alphanums, CharsNotIn, ZeroOrMore, Dict

# Define header
priority = Suppress("<") + Word(alphanums) + Suppress(">")
version = Word(alphanums) + Suppress(" ")
timestamp = CharsNotIn(" ") + Suppress(" ")
hostname = CharsNotIn(" ") + Suppress(" ")
appname = CharsNotIn(" ") + Suppress(" ")
procid = CharsNotIn(" ") + Suppress(" ")
msgid = CharsNotIn("\n")
header = priority + version + timestamp + hostname + appname + procid + msgid

# Define key-value pairs
key = Word(alphanums + "_")
value = CharsNotIn("\n")
pair = key + Suppress("=") + value
kv_pairs = Dict(pair + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(",") + pair))

# Define message format
message = header + Suppress(" ") + kv_pairs

# Open input and output files
with open("syslog.txt") as input_file, open("syslog_output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        try:
            # Convert to key-value format
            parsed_message = message.parseString(line.strip())
            kv_message = " ".join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in parsed_message.items()])

            # Write the message to the output file
            output_file.write(parsed_message + "\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to parse line: {line} with error: {e}")

            continue
```

I get 2 Exceptions when I run the script and I printed the `header` and `message` outputs:

```
Failed to parse line: "Whole Syslog Text"
 with error: Expected ' ', found '2022'  (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)

Failed to parse line: 
 with error: Expected '<'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Header:  {Suppress:('<') W:(0-9A-Za-z) Suppress:('>') W:(0-9A-Za-z) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:(
)}

Message:  {Suppress:('<') W:(0-9A-Za-z) Suppress:('>') W:(0-9A-Za-z) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:( ) Suppress:(' ') !W:(
) Suppress:(' ') Dict:({W:(0-9A-Z_a-z) Suppress:('=') !W:(
) [{Suppress:(',') W:(0-9A-Z_a-z) Suppress:('=') !W:(
)}]...})}
```

I want to my output_file to look like this:

```
<140>1 2022-05-02T08:31:22.478Z platform dataexport - syslog_variation -
key=value
key=value
key=value
...
```

I need to have the header for me to identify which type of log is on FortiSIEM.

Comment: pyparsing skips whitespace by default. Try removing all the ` + Suppress(" ")` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, pyparsing skips whitespace by default, so all the `+ Suppress(" ")` terms should be removed.

`CharsNotIn` is an exception to the whitespace-skipping rule, I find `Word(printables)` works better.

I replaced your `timestamp`, `hostname`, etc. terms with `Word(printables)`, as this:

```py
timestamp = Word(printables)
hostname = Word(printables)
appname = Word(printables)
procid = Word(printables)
msgid = rest_of_line
header = priority + version + timestamp + hostname + appname + '-' + procid + '-' + msgid
```

I used this code to test the parser:

```py
header.run_tests("""\
    <140>1 2022-05-02T08:31:22.478Z platform dataexport - syslog_variation - {"key"=value, info:{"key"=value, "key"=value, "key"=value}, info2:{"key"=value, "key"=value},"key"=value}
    """)
```

and got this:

```
<140>1 2022-05-02T08:31:22.478Z platform dataexport - syslog_variation - {"key"=value, info:{"key"=value, "key"=value, "key"=value}, info2:{"key"=value, "key"=value},"key"=value}
['140', '1', '2022-05-02T08:31:22.478Z', 'platform', 'dataexport', '-', 'syslog_variation', '-', ' {"key"=value, info:{"key"=value, "key"=value, "key"=value}, info2:{"key"=value, "key"=value},"key"=value}']
```

You'll have to refine your definition of the key-value pairs. Use pyparsing's `QuotedString('"')` for the `key`, since it is some value in quotes. For `value`, you'll need to be more careful to just read up to the next comma or `}`, not all the way to the `\n` at end of line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time, this is almost what I need, I just need to Suppress the "-" and have the JSON part without any {} and just the key=value part, I did try some other things Yesterday with no success, like defining Regex expressions on the header and body definitions. I will give updates